# Mach tab or 8 spaces at beginning of a line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a data file with mixed tabs and 8 space indentation.  I only want to match the lines of the first indentation.  So if I have the following data file, I only want to match lines 1 & 2.

```
        line 1 - 8 spaces
        line 2 - tab
                line 3 - 2 tabs
                line 4 - 16 spaces
```

The following returns all the lines as I would expect since I am not specifying the beginning of the line in the regex.

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    match = re.search(r'[\t|        ]line (?P<data>.*)', line)
    if match:
        print match.group('data')
```

Output:

```
1 - 8 spaces
2 - tab
3 - 2 tabs
4 - 16 spaces
```

When I add the ^ to the regex to match the beginning of the line only line 2 matches. I assume the ^ is interacting with the alternation somehow, but do not know how.

```
for line in fileinput.input():
    match = re.search(r'^[\t|        ]line (?P<data>.*)', line)
    if match:
        print match.group('data')
```

Output:

```
2 - tab
```

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are using `[..]` (creating a *character class*, of which only one character will be used) instead of the more likely *grouping* `(..)`.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets are a set of characters to match, in your case tab, | or space. Use the round ones:

```
match = re.search(r'^(?:\t|        )line (?P<data>.*)', line)
```

Comment: `(\t| {8})` is a bit easier on the eye ;)